# How to replicate multidimensioanl cube dimension Unaryoperator in analysis services Tabular model

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, ssas-tabular, multidimensional-cube

I am migrating a multidimensional model to a tabular model. Some of the dimensions are using unaryoperators property in their columns. Can someone please guide me how to replicate the unaryoperator feature in the analysis services tabular model?

Regards
Arif

Comment: Do you know what this is meant to do? Here's the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/parent-child-dimension-attributes-unary-operators?view=asallproducts-allversions This is likely achievable in DAX but we don't know what actuall expression you have. The doc says it could be any of these `+ - * / ~`

Comment: Also read https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/understanding-functions-for-parent-child-hierarchies-in-dax